# Image slider not showing all the slides

Tags: android

I am developing a welcome screen which will show four slides. I have created the adapter and set it in the activity. Every thing is working fine but the problem is the screen only showing first and third slide. But if I scroll manually I can see all the screens. I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Here is my activity class:

```
public class ProgramLandingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String TAG = ProgramLandingActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    ActivityProgramLandingBinding binding;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private int[] layouts = {
            R.drawable.slider3,
            R.drawable.slider1,
            R.drawable.slider2,
           R.drawable.slider4};

    private int[] icons = {
            R.drawable.note,
            R.drawable.mic,
            R.drawable.up_arrow,
            R.drawable.weight};

    private String[] text = {
            "Personalized Running Programs \n and flexible calender",
            "Audio tips in Hindi and English \n From your mentors,\n Gul Panag and Milind Soman",
            "Track your running, see achievements and share daily progress","includes weight loss and running performance nutrition plans"};

    private ArrayList<Integer> layoutArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> layouticons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<String> layouttext = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static int currentPage = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_program_landing);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }

        intializeViews();

        setAdapter();

    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        for (int i = 0; i < layouts.length; i++) {
            layoutArray.add(layouts[i]);
            layouticons.add(icons[i]);
            layouttext.add(text[i]);
            myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(this, layoutArray,layouticons,layouttext);
            viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
            CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

            Log.d("laypou_length", String.valueOf(layouts.length));

        // Auto start of viewpager
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (currentPage == layouts.length) {
                        currentPage = 0;
                    }
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                }
            };
            Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
            swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(Update);
                }
            }, 2500, 2500);

            indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    currentPage = position;

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
        }
    }


    private void intializeViews() {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    }
```

My adapter class:

```
class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private ArrayList<Integer> layouts;
    private ArrayList<Integer> icons;
    private ArrayList<String> text;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Integer> layouts, ArrayList<Integer> icons,ArrayList<String> text ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layouts=layouts;
        this.icons = icons;
        this.text=text;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider,container,false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView)myImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextViewWithFont slider_text = (TextViewWithFont)myImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_program_landing_body);

        myImage.setImageResource(layouts.get(position));
        icon.setImageResource(icons.get(position));
        slider_text.setText(text.get(position));
        container.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
        return myImageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**
you can user time for auto scroll like this

```
Timer timer;
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, 3000); // delay*/

 private class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                    current += 1;
                } else {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen this link. But I want auto scroll.

Comment: thanks but I found out the issue and also fixed it. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in the 'viewpager.setCurrentPage' put prints for the 'currentPage' there and see if it is getting called twice.

Let me know the observation in the comments. 
Cheers :)